# list with nested for each loops

Tags: java

I have two integer list. for eg. list1 has 1,2,3,4,5 and list2 has 3,4,5,6. how to compare both the list using for each loop and finally print the answer as 3,4,5 separately 1,2 seperate and 6 separately. only using for each loop

Comment: you can use set. put list1's element in set1, and put list2 element in set2. for list1, find the different elements and common elements. for list2, find the different element in set1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service. Also, what efforts have you put to solve your problem, please add?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> same = new ArrayList<>();             
    for(Integer i : list1){
        if(list2.contains(i)){
            same.add(i);                
            list2.remove(i);
        }
    }
    list1.removeAll(same);
```